# Multiple forms on same page using same directive AND one form inside an element directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive, dom-events

**BACKGROUND:** I'm trying to create a "halt navigation if form is dirty" directive. I've looked at several questions/examples on SO and I've put together something that is somewhat functional, but not quite right. I'm trying to use this directive as an attribute on multiple forms throughout our web application.

**PROBLEM:** I have a page that contains two `<form>` elements ("form1" and "form2") that are nested within `<tab>` elements. Form2 is further nested inside a custom element directive.

When either form is dirty and I try to navigate to another page (UI router change), I get the expected custom prompt from our prompt service. However if I attempt to reload the page, I only get a browser generated prompt when form2 is dirty. There is no prompt when form1 is dirty.

Can someone please guide me on how to generate the browser prompt when form1 is dirty and there's a window event such as reload?

---

**RELEVANT HTML**

```
<!-- "main" view -->
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Heading1">
        <form name="FORM1" class="form-horizontal" form-dirty>
            <!-- FORM STUFF -->
        </form>
    </tab>  
    <tab heading="Heading2">
        <this-contains-form2 data="objOnScope"></this-contains-form2>
    </tab>
</tabset>

<!-- "thisContainsForm2" template -->
<form name="FORM2" class="form-horizontal" form-dirty>
    <!-- FORM STUFF -->
</form>
```

---

**RELEVANT JAVASCRIPT**

```
// "form-dirty" directive
angular.module('webapp.shared').directive('formDirty', ['$state', 'DlgPromptService', function($state, DlgPromptService) {      
    return {
        scope: {theForm: '=name'},
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('theForm', function () {

                // if there's a UI router change    
                scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams){

                    // WHEN FORM1 DIRTY:  PROMPT AND CONSOLE-LOG BOTH FORMS
                    // WHEN FORM2 DIRTY:  PROMPT AND CONSOLE-LOG BOTH FORMS

                    console.log(scope.theForm);

                    // if form was not modified
                    if ( !scope.theForm.$dirty ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        // if form was modified then intervene

                        // halt the route change
                        event.preventDefault();

                        // prompt user
                        DlgPromptService.confirm('Unsaved Changes',
                            'This form has unsaved changes.<br/>'
                            +'Are you sure you want to leave?')
                        .then(function () {
                            // we will proceed with the route change
                            scope.theForm.$setPristine();
                            $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
                        })
                    }
                })

                // if there's a window change (reload, etc)
                window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {

                    // WHEN FORM1 DIRTY:  NO PROMPT, NO CONSOLE LOG
                    // WHEN FORM2 DIRTY:  PROMPT AND CONSOLE-LOG FORM2

                    console.log(scope.theForm);

                    // if form was not modified             
                    if ( !scope.theForm.$dirty ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        // prompt
                        return "prompt";
                    }
                }

                scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
                })  
            })
        }
    }
}])

// "thisContainsForm2" directive
angular.module('webapp.shared').directive('thisContainsForm2', function() {

    var controller = function($scope, $http, $state, DlgPromptService) {
        // CONTROLLER STUFF
    }

    return {
        scope : {data: '='},
        templateUrl : 'shared/thisContainsForm2.html',
        controller : controller
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use ui bootstraps tab implementation you have to be aware that all tabs are always rendered, but all inactive ones are set to 'display: none'

in this case both form-dirty directives are active at the same time, which then is an issue as the second tab overrides the first tabs window.onbeforeunload function

use jQuerys event mechanism for that to be able to register multiple such listeners or code your own solution

the problem probably also exists if you just put 2 forms below each other on the same page -> only the second one will be treated correctly on before unload

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that was my suspicion as well.  That's a good suggestion about multiple event listeners, I'll look into that.